# plotting google map in shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, ggmap

I have a problem n my shiny app when i attempt to plot a map on the web app i get this

> Error: argument is of length zero

this is the part that responsible for map plotting in my server side

```
  output$SentiMap <- renderPlot({
validate(
  need(input$entity1 != "", 'Please enter a word')
)
LocTweet <- as.data.frame(entityscores(), optional = FALSE)
Loc <- as.data.frame(entity1(), optional = FALSE)
LocTweet$Loc <- Loc$V3
print(LocTweet)
#1-Collect only Negative tweets and put in new dataframe called Negative
AgainstTw <- LocTweet[(LocTweet$score == 'Against'),] #
#2-Callcolate the frequency of negative tweets fo each city
AgainstTw <- ddply(AgainstTw , .(AgainstTw$Loc), nrow)
names(AgainstTw) <- c("Location","Freq")
#3-Find lat and long for the cities founded in the tweets
city.limits <- geocode(as.character(AgainstTw$Location))
AgainstTw$lon <- city.limits$lon
AgainstTw$lat <- city.limits$lat    

#5- we will repeat the same process for the SupportTW tweets 
SupportTW <-  LocTweet[(LocTweet$score == 'With'),]
SupportTW <- ddply(SupportTW , .(SupportTW$Loc), nrow)
names(SupportTW) <- c("Location","Freq")
city.limits <- geocode(as.character(SupportTW$Location))
SupportTW$lon <- city.limits$lon
SupportTW$lat <- city.limits$lat

map <- get_map(location = 'Middle East', zoom = 5)

#7 Plote the map with dots over the cities
print(ggmap(map) +  
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = sqrt(AgainstTw$Freq)), data = AgainstTw, alpha = .7, col = "red")+##this one to plot the Negative tweets
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = sqrt(SupportTW$Freq)), data = SupportTW, alpha = .4, col = "green")##this one to plot the SupportTW tweets
))
})
```

i tried different methods but nothing worked please help me.

Comment: yes thanks, i corrected the code, but still the same error

Comment: Why are you not using leaflet for this?

Comment: what is leaflet, and why should i use it?

Comment: here's the description. https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

Comment: I'd recommend leaflet too.